# Does the length of a violin/guitar string affect the sustain time of the violin/guitar string after being plucked with a constant force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, energy, waves

I can't find much information on this topic, and I'm planning on performing an experiment on it to find a relationship between the length and the sustain time.

Comment: Define 'sustain time'.

Comment: the length of time the string vibrates and the sound can be heard after being plucked.

Answer (score 2):

The faster the string moves the higher the air friction, hence the higher the production of sound and heat. The speed depends on amplitude and tone. So higher tones fade out first.

I assume the string is not plucked in vacuum.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complex problem.

For any string connected to a radiating surface like a violin or guitar body, the primary determinant of the decay time will be the impedance match between the string end and the radiating surface, and the radiation resistance of the surface. A good match minimizes the decay time by allowing quick energy transfer out of the string. High radiation resistance further minimizes decay time by allowing quick energy transfer between the radiating surface and the air that surrounds it.

Note that both the impedance match and the radiation resistance are frequency-dependent which means the decay time will be a strong function of the driving frequency, no matter what kind of string is being used in the system.

Note also that the aerodynamic drag on a string vibrating in air rises very fast with the velocity of the string, unless the string is vibrating in a vacuum. This means that the high frequencies will always decay faster than the lows will and this is also true in the case of the wood typically used to make violin and guitar bodies.

Finally, note that strings contain internal friction, especially so for strings made
of organic materials and strings with multiple layers of wrapping on them. This adds damping which preferentially kills off the fastest-moving vibrations on the string i.e., all the higher harmonics. this high-frequency internal damping is most pronounced for very short strings- where the string length is of order ~100 diameters or less.